# insert и select

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Первая таблица **"peoples"**

```
id|name

1|Алексей
2|Борис
3|Валерий
```

Вторая таблица **"cars"**

```
id|brand

1|Ауди
2|Тойота
```

В третьей таблице **"peoples_cars"** необходимо получить

```
id|name|brand

1|Алексей|Ауди
2|Алексей|Тойота
3|Борис|Ауди
4|Борис|Тойота
5|Валерий|Ауди
6|Валерий|Тойота
```

Как сделать **insert** в третью таблицу с 2 **select**-ами чтобы получить то что мне нужно?

Comment: CROSS JOIN произведет то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Или просто перечислить таблицы во FROM через запятую, если БД позволяет такое

Comment: @Anatoly, вы имели ввиду так? insert into peoples_cars (name, brand) select name, brand from peoples, cars

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, вы имели ввиду так? insert into peoples_cars (name, brand) select name, brand from peoples cross join cars

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: @Anatoly, что-то никак не соображу почему это должно работать, ведь INSERT требует 2 поля, а SELECTу неоткуда взять два поля в каждой таблице, ведь там по одному полю в каждой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как.

[SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e6bh91Dq1WDr51USbaWEFY/0)

Разъяснения:

- в ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY ...) ORDER BY является обязательным.
  Неясно, какой порядок сортировки требуется. Вот почему я использовал
  NULL.
- AS используется как псевдоним. Это не обязательно.

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE people (id INT, fname NVARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO people (id, fname) VALUES
(1, 'Алексей'),
(2, 'Борис'),
(3, 'Валерий');

CREATE TABLE cars (id INT, brand NVARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO cars (id, brand) VALUES
(1, 'Ауди'),
(2, 'Тойота');

select ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( 
        ORDER BY NULL 
    ) RowNum
 , fname, brand 
from people CROSS JOIN cars;
```

**Результат**

```
+---------+----------+--------+
| RowNum  |  fname   | brand  |
+---------+----------+--------+
|      1  | Алексей  | Ауди   |
|      2  | Алексей  | Тойота |
|      3  | Борис    | Ауди   |
|      4  | Борис    | Тойота |
|      5  | Валерий  | Ауди   |
|      6  | Валерий  | Тойота |
+---------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Отдельное спасибо за сервис по проверке выражений SQL, не знал о таком

Comment: @tonchikp, Рад слышать, что предложенное решение работает на вас. Не забудьте пометить это как ответ.

Comment: Сократил и переработал ваш вариант, мне же нужен был insert

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e6bh91Dq1WDr51USbaWEFY/2

Comment: Не знаю, ссылка показывает то же что и у меня или нет. Сделал так insert into peoples_cars (name, brand) select name, brand from peoples CROSS JOIN cars

Comment: Так что всё работает, огромное спасибо!